# Even dimensionality for skew-symmetric form

Tags: abstract-algebra

From Humphreys' *Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory*, written in parentheses:

> (It can be shown that even dimensionality is a necessary condition for existence of a non-degenerate bilinear form satisfying $f(v,w)=-f(w,v)$.)

Why is this? Suppose we have odd dimensionality. So $n$ is odd. We have an $n\times n$ matrix $S$ with independent rows such that $v^TSw=-w^TSv$ for all vectors $v,w$. How does this provide a contradiction?

Comment: It's the _non-degeneracy_ requirement that forces even dimension.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Well, non-degeneracy forces the rows of $S$ to be independent. How does that force even dimension?

Comment: My previous comment was made automatically by the software - the linked question is not literally a duplicate, but it contains an answer to this question (which is what the close notification will say if this question is closed as a duplicate).